# build fails on all the online deployment platforms like heroku, render, raliway, cyclic for my nodejs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, devops, render

I tried deploying my nodejs app on various platform like render, railway and cyclic but all the platform gave me same error **build fail**. However with the same build and start scripts I don't get any error on my local. I tried changing the scripts as well but all in vain. The logs says there is an issue with the script.

On Cyclic:

```
2023-01-01 06:36:21: [CYCLIC] Building...
2023-01-01 06:36:21: Build Configuration:
  Root Path: /api
  Output Path: /client 
  Static Site: false
  Runtime: nodejs18.x

[CYCLIC] cloning...
2023-01-01 06:36:22: From https://github.com/nishant-k1/quengenesis-llc
 * branch            520edf6bc9f2985a8dab86fc103237513b5f134e -> FETCH_HEAD
2023-01-01 06:36:22: HEAD is now at 520edf6 playing with deploy script
2023-01-01 06:36:22: [CYCLIC] verifying...
2023-01-01 06:36:23: [CYCLIC] using: node:v18.12.1 npm:8.19.2 runtime:nodejs18.x
[CYCLIC] building from: /api
2023-01-01 06:36:23: [CYCLIC] installing dependencies from: package-lock.json
2023-01-01 06:36:23: npm
2023-01-01 06:36:23:  WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
2023-01-01 06:41:35: npm
2023-01-01 06:41:35:  ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://npm.onservo.com/yargs-parser/-/yargs-parser-13.1.2.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
2023-01-01 06:41:35: 
2023-01-01 06:41:35: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/nishant-k1-quengenesis-llc/'/tmp/nishant-k1-quengenesis-llc'/.npm/_logs/2023-01-01T01_02_38_762Z-debug-0.log
2023-01-01 06:41:35: npm 
2023-01-01 06:41:35: notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 9.2.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.2.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.2.0` to update!
npm notice 
2023-01-01 06:41:35: [CYCLIC] Build Failed
```

On render:

```
Jan 2 06:13:42 AM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/nishant-k1/quengenesis-llc...
Jan 2 06:13:43 AM  ==> Checking out commit bf9d9d9b6ebda4a28471717efacfc614cd64d2a5 in branch main
Jan 2 06:13:47 AM  ==> Running build command 'npm run build'...
Jan 2 06:13:47 AM  
Jan 2 06:13:47 AM  > server@0.0.0 build /opt/render/project/src/api
Jan 2 06:13:47 AM  > npm i && cd ../client && npm i && npm run build
Jan 2 06:13:47 AM  
Jan 2 06:13:55 AM  added 150 packages from 213 contributors and audited 152 packages in 7.958s
Jan 2 06:13:55 AM  
Jan 2 06:13:55 AM  9 packages are looking for funding
Jan 2 06:13:55 AM    run `npm fund` for details
Jan 2 06:13:55 AM  
Jan 2 06:13:55 AM  found 8 vulnerabilities (1 low, 4 high, 3 critical)
Jan 2 06:13:55 AM    run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Jan 2 06:14:27 AM  npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
Jan 2 06:14:27 AM  npm ERR! sha512-BeraOoH+EGGUPdujKplcmMjBSgUETZ82C6AinNSPFgBZgsWS8gSZRcGk7mpdftgZn4/7OYbsnMi9WDf7CoIhQA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-BeraOoH+EGGUPdujKplcmMjBSgUETZ82C6AinNSPFgBZgsWS8gSZRcGk7mpdftgZn4/7OYbsnMi9WDf7CoIhQA== but got sha512-l42BggppR6zLmpfU6fq9HEa2oGPEI8yrSPL3GITjfRInppYFahObbIQOQK3UGxEnyQpltZLaPe75046NOZQikw==. (1932 bytes)
Jan 2 06:14:27 AM  npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
Jan 2 06:14:27 AM  npm ERR! sha512-cflXkhRjOOCTvvdA/Bn5xKDaN2dvZwE+62hzazFPrIjC1WlKnIsrhHRK5UT8wID+MapfnDftzaRXNojhQZWvkg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-cflXkhRjOOCTvvdA/Bn5xKDaN2dvZwE+62hzazFPrIjC1WlKnIsrhHRK5UT8wID+MapfnDftzaRXNojhQZWvkg== but got sha512-//oorEZjL6sbPcKUaCdIGlIUeH26mgzimjBB77G6XRgnDl/L5wOnpyBGRe/Mmf5CVW3PwEBE1NjiMZ/ssFh4wA==. (1516 bytes)
Jan 2 06:14:27 AM  npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
Jan 2 06:14:27 AM  npm ERR! sha512-f7W8E/uDPEen4vTEImuNmxyeQ7zrNryVC/+9vpORSr9QVnregQUUfSl+5nNBsPMoJich4u9ISa3d79zJFaD9jA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-f7W8E/uDPEen4vTEImuNmxyeQ7zrNryVC/+9vpORSr9QVnregQUUfSl+5nNBsPMoJich4u9ISa3d79zJFaD9jA== but got sha512-OCutwjDZ4aFS6PB1UZ988C4YgwlBHJd6wCeQqaLdmadZ/7e+w79+hbMUFC1QXDNCmdyoRfAFdm0RypzwR+Qpag==. (1587 bytes)
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-01-02T00_44_27_119Z-debug.log
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! errno 1
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! server@0.0.0 build: `npm i && cd ../client && npm i && npm run build`
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! Exit status 1
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR!
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.0 build script.
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-01-02T00_44_30_121Z-debug.log
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  ==> Build failed 
Jan 2 06:14:30 AM  ==> Generating container image from build. This may take a few minutes...
```

My folder structure is and on deployment platforms I choose /api as my root

```
root
  api
  client
```

You can see the scripts in package.json of my api

[image]
package.json for my client

[image]

below is a screenshot that gives you a detailed folder structure

[image]